# Build time too high when using Tailwind CSS with a Svelte app

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, postcss

> **EDIT** - By using SvelteKit starter app from [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and applying tailwindcss as a adder by
> following steps through this
> [repo](https://github.com/svelte-add/tailwindcss) I was able to
> compile the svelte-app with tailwindcss utilities in real-time.
>
> **But would still like to know about the issue I mentioned below and a fix for it.**

Trying to create a Svelte app and add Tailwind CSS Framework to it.

So as of now:
I have Installed the svelte app and added the Tailwind CSS and the other requirements based on this [website](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-tailwind-on-a-svelte-site/) and I am able to use Tailwind classes and utilities in my app.

Now the problem is even for such simple project the build time for the app is too high (~19s) which is not ideal to work with.

> All other file configs and properties are default other than the changes mentioned in the link above to add tailwind to a svelte project.

```
<!--------- App.svelte --------->
...

<main>
    <h1 class="text-purple-400">Hello World!</h1>
</main>


<style global lang="postcss">
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;

  ...
</style>
```

```
############################ Terminal output ############################

bundles src/main.ts → public\build\bundle.js...
created public\build\bundle.js in 18.7s

[2021-11-25 20:10:38] waiting for changes...
  [20:10:38] 200 ─ 0.87ms ─ /
  [20:10:38] 200 ─ 1.29ms ─ /global.css
  [20:10:38] 200 ─ 1.68ms ─ /build/bundle.js
  [20:10:38] 200 ─ 2.82ms ─ /build/bundle.css
  [20:10:38] 200 ─ 0.73ms ─ /favicon.png
```

So till now what I've tried and understood in that process:

1. This excessive build time is caused due to the fact that the Tailwind `utilities.css` file is rebuilt after every change made in `<style>` of the app. (And also since this is the biggest file in comparison with `base.css` `components.css` and hence takes more time)
2. One way to fix this issue is to separately import of these Tailwind files which would avoid the rebuilding of `utilities.css` whenever a style change is made in the app. (I am not clear how this would solve the problem)

I read through many GitHub discussions related to this but I still was not able to fix my issue or wrap my mind around that how importing the files separately is making a difference?

So my final question is:

**What is the way to fix this problem (reduce the build-time when using Tailwind) and how is that fix solving the problem?**

Thank you in advance :).

P.S. - This is my first question here so sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: Can you share your tailwind.config.js file with us? Which version of tailwindcss do you use?  If it's v2.x, have you tried using purge option or jit mode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same issue. For me https://github.com/svelte-add/svelte-add worked fine. You can add tailwind and postcss using the below commands

```
npx svelte-add postcss
npx svelte-add tailwindcss
```

**Edit 1 :- ** You can also set the purge option in tailwind.config.js option to one of the below values and it will also speed up your build time.

```
purge:{
   enabled: true
}
```

or

```
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
purge:{
  enabled: production
}
```